# Why does Proxima Nova text bleed at certain font sizes and weights depending on the OS and screen resolution?

Tags: css, fonts

We are using Proxima Nova on our site. As it is one of the more common fonts, I am posting to see if anyone has seen any similar issues.

**The Problem:** When on Windows, any browser, certain screen resolutions, certain text sizes, and certain font weights bleed together making text hard to read. For example, lowercase "i" looks like an "l" because there is no separation between the dot and the body. This is making the boss not very happy. These issues do not occur on Mac OS X, with or without smoothing. For some Windows users, changing the screen resolution fixes it.

Here's a group of screen shots showing the issue best I can (note: Moodi is a made up company, sorry if there is a real Moodi out there reading this)....

[proxima nova error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CXnO.png)

Notice the clarity of the "i" on Mac and on font-size: 16px.

So, I am aware we can change the font (not very desirable), change the font weight, change the font size, etc. I am more wondering if anyone else has experienced this, what causes it, and is something wrong in our setup that is causing these issues since this is a very popular font.

Our default css is...

```
body {
    font-family: proxima-nova, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
    line-height: 1.6;
    text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

And the example broken text includes these extras...

```
.btn-link {
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.025em;
}
```

If anyone has experienced this or knows why this occurs that would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried CSS anti-aliasing properties, like `font-smooth:always;` and 
`-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` to see if it normalizes the behavior?

Comment: oh boy, time for you to read *all* off the [Raster Tragedy](http://www.rastertragedy.com). tl;dr version: "fonts are designed on 1000 unit (or more) rectangles. Then we try to scale that down to like... 16 units. We're good, but not *that* good; despite our best efforts it's going to go wrong unless you literally start using bitmaps". (which, to be fair, OpenType explicitly allows you to do in addition to the nice vector outlines)

Comment: @Quantastical  :-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased is already being used, but that is mac only where there is no issue. And unless I am missing something, font-smooth isn't standard and shouldn't be used in production sites... but either way I tried it and nothing happened. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Wow, thanks for the homework assignment! ;-p Unfortunately, I don't have the time at the moment to read through it all. Based on your tl;dr, Fonts are created at this large size and when we shrink them down, issues occur. That makes total sense... but why is it totally fine at 14px and 16px but not 15px... and only on windows?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the reading material. Looks interesting.

Antiwebbit, sorry about the suggestions. I'm think font-smooth is just some crappy IE hack or something. I have seen a lot of differences between a lot of browsers, OSes, and fonts and have yet to find a uniform approach to normalize font rendering across them all.

Comment: @antiwebbite mostly "because integers". If you scale down something designed for 1000 units, to something that cleanly divides 1000 (say, 10 or 20) then it'll look good with minimal hinting (fonts can come with instructions on how to deal with issues-from-scaling). However, when cycling through non-integer scales you can easily end up with situations where you either need *a lot* of detailed hinting (and hinting is a lot of work so many font makers just rely on generic generators) or bitmap fallbacks (which are rarely used except by big name, loads-of-staff companies)

Comment: @antiwebbite And of course each OS has its own font engine, so just because it looks right on Linux or OSX, doesn't mean it looks right on Windows unfortunately. In fact, Windows has THEE engines (due to backward compatibility support), and which one is used depends on which one the programmers of the application you use picked in their code. Toggle `directwrite.force-enabled` in Firefox's `about:config`, reload FF, and see if it still looks bad. If not: hurray it's "specifically this font plus specifically this font engine" that's the culprit =/

Comment: @antiwebbite did you found solution for this ? I too facing same issue